# jQuery + regular expression how to replace this URI

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a simple URI that looks like the following:

```
/stuff/assets/1234/asset/foobar
```

What's the proper way with jQuery to replace the assets with another word? if I do a simple `.replace('asset', 'something')` it changes the URI to `/stuff/somethings/1234/something/foobar`. I only want to replace the second asset, not the first one.

I also tried using PCRE based \b for bareword, but that didn't do it.

What's the proper way with jQuery to change only the second asset with something?

Answer (score 0):

Could do a simple

```
.replace('/asset/', '/something/');
```